# convert byte size into human readable format in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

Am trying to Create a static method `String formatSize(long sizeInBytes)`
This method needs to return the most appropriate representation for the provided file size (in bytes)
to a human-readable format with at least 2 decimal places (except for bytes).

here is my code

```
public class HexEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatSize(2147483647));
        System.out.println(formatSize(123));
        System.out.println(formatSize(83647));
        System.out.println(formatSize(9585631));
        System.out.println(formatSize(188900977659375L));
    }
    public static String floatForm (double d){
       return new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d);
    }

    public static String formatSize(long size) {


        double B = 1 * 8;
        double kibit = 1024;
        double KiB = B * kibit;
        double MiB = KiB * kibit;
        double GiB = MiB * kibit;
        double TiB = GiB * kibit;
        double Pib = TiB * kibit;

        if (size < kibit) {
            return size + " byte";

        } else if (size < KiB) {
            double result = size / kibit;
            return floatForm (result) + " Kibit";

        } else if (size < MiB) {
            double result = size / KiB;
            return floatForm (result) + " KiB";

        } else if (size < GiB) {
            double result = size / MiB;
            return floatForm (result) + " MiB";

        } else if (size < TiB) {
            double result = size / GiB;
            return floatForm (result) + " GiB";

        } else if (size < Pib) {
            double result = size / TiB;
            return floatForm (result) + " TiB";
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

these are my inputs and expect outputs

**Input               Output**

```
2147483647          2.00 GiB
123                 123 bytes
83647               81.69 KiB
9585631             9.14 MiB
188900977659375     171.80 TiB
```

but when my code runs it gives different **outputs**

```
    256 MiB
    123 byte
    10.21 KiB
    1.14 MiB
    21.48 TiB
```

Am I getting wrong? or something

Comment: Actually, you are doing it wrong.
The biggest byte input should be in if statement, second biggest should be in else if statement and so on. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing by bits but your input is *already* in bytes, not bits. So except for the < KB calculation you're ending up with results that are all 1/8th of the expected size calculations.

Give the following code a whirl (print statements added just to sanity check the divisors):

```java
        double KiB = Math.pow(2, 10);
        double MiB = Math.pow(2, 20);
        double GiB = Math.pow(2, 30);
        double TiB = Math.pow(2, 40);
        double Pib = Math.pow(2, 50);

        NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        System.out.println("KiB: " + df.format(KiB));
        System.out.println("MiB: " + df.format(MiB));
        System.out.println("GiB: " + df.format(GiB));
        System.out.println("TiB: " + df.format(TiB));
        System.out.println("Pib: " + df.format(Pib));

        if (size < KiB) {
            return size + " byte";

        } else if (size < MiB) {
            double result = size / KiB;
            return floatForm(result) + " KiB";

        /* remaining code is identical to yours */
```

Comment: BTW I assume this isn't applicable here but there are of course available libraries that will do this work for you. Apache Commons `FileUtils` for instance:


`FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size)`

Comment: thanks, friend, actually my KiB calculation was wrong

Comment: NP glad to help. Yeah it was all fine you just didn't need the `B` as a factor...